# Strange execution jump when using async/await and System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I have the following method:

```
public async Task ExecuteAsync()
{
     Task<IEnumerable<Comment>> gettingComments = RetrieveComments();

     Dictionary<string, ReviewManager> reviewers = ConfigurationFacade.Repositories.ToDictionary(name => name, name => new ReviewManager(name));

     IEnumerable<Comment> comments = await gettingComments;

     Parallel.ForEach(reviewers, (reviewer) => {
          Dictionary<Comment, RevisionResult> reviews = reviewer.Value.Review(comments);

          int amountModerated = ModerateComments(reviews.Where(r => r.Value.IsInsult), "hide");
     });
}
```

My `ModerateComments` method looks like the following:

```
private Task<int> ModerateComments(IEnumerable<Comment> comments, string operation)
{
      return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
      {
          int moderationCount = 0;
          Parallel.ForEach(comments, async (comment) => 
          {
               bool moderated = await ModerateComment(comment, operation); //Problem here
               if(moderated)
                   moderationCount++;
          }
          return moderationCount;
      };
}
```

And finally:

```
private async Task<bool> ModerateComment(Comment comment, string operation, string authenticationToken = null)
{
      if(comment == null) return false;

      if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(authenticationToken))
             authenticationToken = CreateUserToken(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));

      string moderationEndpoint = ConfigurationFacade.ModerationEndpoint;

      using(HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage())
      {
          request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
          request.RequestUri = new Uri(moderationEndpoint);
          using(HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request)) //Problem here
          {
               if(!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
               {
                    if(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
                        return await ModerateComment(comment, operation, null); //Retry operation with a new access token
                    else if(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.GatewayTimeout)
                        return await ModerateComment(comment, operation, authenticationToken); //Retry operation

                    return false;
               } 
          }
      }

      return true;
}
```

I'm having a strange problem at runtime. All the above code is working fine except when it reaches the line:

```
using(HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request)) {
      //...
}
```

When I debug my application, this instruction is executed but just after that, it does not throw any exception, nor return anything, it just finish executing and I am derived to the next statement on the `Parallel.ForEach` loop.

It is really hard to explain so I'll post some images:

All good so far, I reach the following line of code:
[image: Image01]

The execution keeps going well and I reach the call to the Moderation API
[image: Image02]

Even if I press F10 (Next statement) in the debugger, the execution flow jumps to the next loop in the Parallel.ForEach loop.

[image: Image03]

As you can see I have breakpoints in the try-catch just i ncase any exception is thrown, but the breakpoint is never activated, neither is activated the breakpoint in `if(moderacion) commentCount++`.

So what happens here? Where did my execution flow went? It just dissapears after sending the POST request to the API.

After continuing the execution, all the elements in the enumerable do the same jump, and therefore, my `commentCount` variable ends up being equal to 0
[image: Image04]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excellent description for a common problem. Parallel.ForEach does not support async lambdas. async methods return once they hit the first await that would need to block. This happens when you issue the HTTP request.

Use one of the common patterns for a parallel async foreach loop.

Comment: Wow, this is indeed interesting! Thank you for your quick response

Answer (score 4):

You don't need `Parallel.ForEach` or `Task.Factory.StartNew` to do IO bound work:

```
private async Task<int> ModerateCommentsAsync(IEnumerable<Comment> comments, string operation)
{
      var commentTasks = comments.Select(comment => ModerateCommentAsync(comment, operation));

      await Task.WhenAll(commentTasks);
      return commentTasks.Count(x => x.Result);
}
```

Common practice is to add the `Async` postfix to an async method.

Comment: I've never thought about using `Select` to grab a collection of Tasks. Typically I just add them manually to a collection before dumping them into a `WhenAll` call. Clever.

Comment: @Johnathan Select is good when you want projection of all the values in the collection